# How to prevent moving text down inside div?

Tags: html, css

```css
.left {
      float: left;
      width: 75%;
      padding: 1px;
      border: 2px solid #eff0f0;
      font-weight: 450;
      font-size: 14px;
      border-right: none;
      text-align: center;  
    }
```

```html
<div class="left">https://temo.derocitycapul.com/?code=1234567</div>
```

Here how it looks on the browser:

[image]

And here how it looks on the small window browser:

[image]

My question is how to prevent sliding the text to another row and make the text inside the div to be in a single line in any browser window size.

Comment: If the text won't fit on the screen what should happen?

Comment: @Paulie_D it should be scrollable

Comment: 'white-space: nowrap'...

Answer (score 1):

`white-space:nowrap` should do the trick. Use `overflow-x:auto` to make it scrollable:

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 2px solid #eff0f0;
  font-weight: 450;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: center;  
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
div{
  width:100px !important;
}
```

```html
<p>With white-space:nowrap: </p><div class="left">https://temo.derocitycapul.com/?code=1234567</div><br/>
<p>Without: </p><div class="left" style="white-space:initial">https://temo.derocitycapul.com/?code=1234567</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it not scrollable

Comment: @Michael What do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 2px solid #eff0f0;
  font-weight: 450;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: center;  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">https://temo.derocitycapul.com/?code=1234567</div>
```